# TypeError: fetch failed

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3, nuxt-auth

I am using `nuxt 3.8.2` with `@auth/core 0.20.0` and facing this issue after `yarn build && node .output/server/index.mjs` when accessing the provider (keycloak) sign-in page ...

```
[auth][error] TypeError: fetch failed
    at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11730:11)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Here's my package.json ...

```
{
  "name": "next-auth-nuxt",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt prepare && nuxt dev",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "preview": "nuxt preview"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/eslint-config": "^0.1.1",
    "eslint": "^8.29.0",
    "h3": "1.9.0",
    "nuxt": "3.8.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/core": "^0.20.0",
    "@hattip/adapter-node": "^0.0.35",
    "@vueform/nuxt": "^1.4.0",
    "@vueform/vueform": "^1.6.5",
    "ag-grid-community": "^31.0.1",
    "ag-grid-vue3": "^31.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.30.1",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.10.2"
  }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To be explicit ... This `works fine` (when it comes to `signin` into `keycloak`) - `yarn run dev --host`. This `doesn't work` (when it comes to `signin` into `keycloak`) - `node .output/server/index.mjs`